# Linking error (LNK1136 or C1001) initializing a two dimensional string array in Visual C++ but not other primitives

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio-2012, multidimensional-array, visual-studio-2013

In **Visual Studio 2013 SP4** I created a **Visual C++** Console app (happens in unit test project too).  I have the following code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    double(*i)[2] = new double[3][2] {
        { 1, 2 },
        { 3, 4 },
        { 5, 6 }
    };

    std::string(*s)[2] = new std::string[3][2] {
        { "1", "2" },
        { "3", "4" },
        { "5", "6" }
    };

    return 0;
}
```

The array *i* is initialized and can be compiled.  When I attempt to compile the second array *s*, I either get:

> *fatal error LNK1136: invalid or corrupt file* on the .obj file,
>
> *error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler*

**Can anyone explain or tell me why this is happening?** I would prefer to avoid using external libraries if possible and I'm more interested in learning why VS2013 SP4 is having difficulty compiling/linking the initialization of the *s* array.

I am aware of the following solution/code:

```
std::string s[3][2] = {
    { "1", "2" },
    { "3", "4" },
    { "5", "6" }
};
```

but I need to allocate memory on the heap and not the stack.  The above code would create the array on the stack.  I would prefer to use "new/new[]" to allocate memory on the heap.

Comment: Why are you dynamically allocating these arrays? Can't you use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead? For example `std::vector<std::array<double, 2>> i = { { ... } };` Or if the size is fixed for both "dinemsions", `std::array<std::array<double, 2>, 3> i = ...`.

Comment: I would prefer to avoid using external libraries if at all possible and I'm more interested on why VS2013 SP4 is having difficulty compiling/linking this code.

Comment: vector and array are not external libraries they are part of the c++ standard library.

Comment: You do know that `std::array` and `std::vector` are part of the *standard library* (what did you think the `std` namespace meant?), which will be linked to *all* C++ programs?

Comment: Still looking for a solution without std::array and std::vector